# This project uses version 5.5.12 of RxJs, which is not supported by Angular v6

Tags: angular, rxjs

I was trying to run a downloaded project but it was giving me this error

> Your global Angular CLI version is greater than your local version. The local Angular CLI version is used.

So I updated cli to latest version.But now I am getting this error.

> This project uses version 5.5.12 of RxJs, which is not supported by Angular v6.

How can I update a specific dependency (in this case rxjs) to latest version?

Comment: try to `npm update` in your project diretory

Comment: Already did that but it doesn't work.

Comment: https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 4):

Try running

```
npm i rxjs@6 --save
```

It can work !!

Answer (score 0):

Go to package.json, change the below line:

```
"rxjs": "^5.5.12"
```

to:

```
"rxjs": "6.3.3"
```

Perform npm update, then ng serve.
This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try running following commands

```
npm i <module name>@<version>(optional) --save
```

> example: -S is the alias of --save

```
npm i rxjs@latest -S

yarn add <module name>@<version>(optional)
```

Or

```
yarn update <module name>@<version>(optional)
yarn update

ng update --all
```

This way you can update all or individual modules.